# Why is my rasterized graphic blank?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, bugs

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier, and persisting through 10.1 or later (OSX 10.10.2)**

---

Consider the following code:

```
jet[u_?NumericQ] := 
  Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, 
      Cyan}, {13/21, Yellow}, {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, 
      RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, u] /; 0 <= u <= 1;
(* jet function get from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9321152/1363677*)
caxis[x_, {min_, max_}] := 
  If[x < min, jet[0], If[x > max, jet[1], jet[(x - min)/(max - min)]]];

data1 = Table[
   Sinc[x*y] + RandomReal[{0., 0.2}], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 0.05}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 0.05}];
data2 = Table[
   Sinc[x*y] + RandomReal[{0., 0.2}], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 0.02}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 0.02}];

Row[{Graphics[Raster[data1, ColorFunction -> (caxis[#, {-0.5, 2}] &)],
    ImageSize -> 200],
  Graphics[Raster[data2, ColorFunction -> (caxis[#, {-0.5, 2}] &)], 
   ImageSize -> 200],
  Graphics[Raster[data2, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"], 
   ImageSize -> 200]}]
```

It gives the output:

[image]

Why is the second plot blank?

If the dynamic updating is turned off, all of the three are blank.

[image]

Why does *Mathematica* behave like this? I'm using OSX 10.8.4 on a Macbook Air with 1.7 GHz Intel Core i5 and 4GB memory.

Comment: You should certainly indicate what version and OS you're working with for this type of question.  The code works fine for me in version 9.0.0 on Mac OSX 10.7.4.

Comment: I'm using OSX 10.8.4.

Comment: Problem confirmed in version 9.0.1 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: All plots are fine here. OS X 10.8.4, MMA 9.0.1

Comment: The code works for version 9.0 on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: @Silvia did you monitor the setting "Dynamic Updating Enabled" in the "Evaluation" menu?

Comment: It still presents blank graphics when I disable the *Dynamic Updating*. The best I can tell is that your `ColorFunction` in the output Cell, which is ``ColorFunction->($CellContext`caxis[#, {-0.5, 2}]& )``, needs *Dynamic Updating* enabled to function.

Comment: Yes I confirmed that. See my last comment please. btw with *Dynamic Updating* enabled, the first time I found the 2nd plot is blank, but then I can't reproduce that.

Comment: I see this in version 9.0.0 but not in version 8.0.4

Comment: MMA8 with OSX 10.6.8 does not exhibit this behavior. All plots displayed with dynamic updating on or off.

Comment: MMA8 with Windows XP does not display middle plot when dynamic updating is on. When dynamic updating is off, nothind is displayed.

Comment: V9.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8 has no problem evaluating this code.

Comment: this is the issue with what was originally my [wavelet scalogram exporting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24381)

Comment: Possibly related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21485/862) question.

Comment: Identical behavior observed here on 7.0.1, 8.0.4, and 9.0.1, on Windows 2003 x64. Middle plot is missing in all cases.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Would you please test 10.0.X on your system?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have tested on 10.0.1, and now I'm install a 10.0.2 and will test that and update the post.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard version 10 cannot be installed on Windows 2003. On Windows 7, 10.0.1 does not exhibit the bug. I didn't install 10.0.2 yet.

Comment: @Oleksandr Thank you.  I forgot about end-of-support with old Windows editions.  (A part of me has trouble calling 2003 *old* -- is it really 2015 *already!?*)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Label this a most bizarre bug -- I can reproduce the problem (v9.0.0.0) -- the fix,
change all those integer fractions in Blend to decimals..

This fails:

```
jet[u_?NumericQ] :=  Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 1/9]}, {1, Red}}, u] /; 0 <= u <= 1
```

This works

```
jet[u_?NumericQ] := Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 0.11111111]}, {1, Red}}, u] /; 0 <= u <= 1
```

Edit: another curiosity.. this should be the same (I think..) normalising the values before passing to the color function.

```
Graphics[Raster[data1, Automatic, {-.05, 2}, 
         ColorFunction -> (caxis[#, {0, 1}] &)], ImageSize -> 200]
```

Although it works, the colors are substantially different.

Comment: neither works with dynamic updating off.

Comment: I agree this is a bug (+1). It also disappears when I remove the `RandomReal` from the definition of the data.